# How to put background image and jquery animation responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a website which contains the various background images. But my query is when I saw in mobile version, every background not shown properly with devices. and I also apply jquery for animation which contains margin-left to margin-top animation in desktop version. So, in mobile device how can I play my jquery animation. My css for background image is as follow.

```
.home
{
background-image:url("../img/sofa.jpg");
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
height:100vh;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Now, my jquery for animation is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   setInterval(function(){  
$("#animate1").fadeIn('slow')
.animate({'margin-left':'220px','margin-`bottom':'20px'},2000,
function(){         $('.1st').animate({'opacity':'0'},1000,
function()    {$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'1'})})
   }).fadeOut();

   $("#animate1").fadeIn('slow')
.animate({'margin-bottom':'0px','margin-left':'-140px'},2000).fadeOut();

  },2000);
    });
```

How can I play my this jquery in mobile version as it contains margin type animation ? Please help me...THANKS in advance..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jquery for background image slideshow and use CSS3 media queries for responsiveness.

```
@media screen {max-device:320px }  @media screen{max-device:600px}
```

likewise you can handle your breakpoints.